# In mpv, how can I start playback at a random moment of a playlist?

Tags: mpv

In `mpv`, there's the [`--start`](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-start) switch, which allows me to provide a number of seconds to skip. This way I can start playback at a random moment in a single file.

And there's [`--shuffle`](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-shuffle) which allows me to start playback at a random file within a given playlist.

I combine both to:

1. choose a random file and
2. start playback at a random moment in that file

with this command line:

```bash
mpv --shuffle --start $POSITION --playlist=/tmp/list.m3u
```

#### Issue

However, the `--start` parameter will be considered for each and every file that follows later on in the list as well and those will also have their first X seconds skipped. I don't want that.

#### What I tried

Currently I invoke `mpv` twice, in sequence, but that's ugly.

#### Questions

Is there a way to have `--start` only affect the very first file played?

Or, even better, get mpv at a completely random moment in the random playlist. So, if the list is 123 minutes, it would start at 31 minutes 13 seconds, regardless of how far or not that would be into the file.

Answer (score 2):

Using a socket, you could start the player in a paused state in the background:

```bash
# with playlist
mpv --shuffle --pause --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket test.m3u &

# without playlist, load a playlist
mpv --shuffle --pause --idle=yes --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket &
echo '{ "command": [ "loadfile", "test.m3u" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

Then seek to the start position of the current title (jumps to the start of the next title if greater than length)

```bash
# seek 100s forward (relative)
echo '{ "command": [ "seek", "+100" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

# seek to 1:30 (absolute)
echo '{ "command": [ "seek", "1:30", "absolute" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

and unpause the player

```bash
echo '{ "command": [ "set_property", "pause", false ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

---

Here is a little bash script `mpvplay.sh` that seeks to a random position of the first title and incorporates the above commands. You need `socat`, `jq` and `shuf`:

```bash
# start player in background
mpv --shuffle --pause --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket "$@" &

# wait until socket exists
while [ ! -S /tmp/mpvsocket ]; do :; done

sleep 0.5 # hack: wait a little longer

# get duration of current title in seconds with fractional part, save as integer
duration=$(echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "duration"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket |
    jq -r '.data | floor')
echo "title duration: $duration"

# get random start position of title
duration=$(shuf -n1 -i0-"$duration")
echo "random seek: $duration"

# seek to position
echo '{ "command": [ "seek", "+'"$duration"'" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

# unpause player
echo '{ "command": [ "set_property", "pause", false ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket

# player to foreground
fg
```

Source the script with your playlist(s) as argument(s):

```bash
. ./mpvplay.sh playlist.m3u
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the M3U directive for time-offset in your playlist file

Suppose your playlist is in **M3U-format** and contains multiple audio-files like the [M3U *Example 1* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U):

```
#EXTM3U
 
#EXTINF:123, Sample artist - Sample title
C:\Documents and Settings\I\My Music\Sample.mp3
 
#EXTINF:321,Example Artist - Example title
C:\Documents and Settings\I\My Music\Greatest Hits\Example.ogg
```

Then you could add the start-offset, applied once for the playlist (not for each file), by adding the **extended M3U directive** for time-offset [`#EXT-X-START: TIME-OFFSET=0`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.5.2), where

> The value of TIME-OFFSET is a signed-decimal-floating-point number of seconds.

#### Insert the time-offset into your playlist

To insert the offset-directive with your given environment-variable `$POSITION` at line 2, you could use [*sed*](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/insert-line-specific-line-number#using-sed) on the command-line:

```bash
sed "2 i #EXT-X-START: TIME-OFFSET=$POSITION" /tmp/list.m3u
```

This results in the modified playlist with your custom time-offset position applied, like for example with time-offset of `1873` seconds:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-START: TIME-OFFSET=1873

#EXTINF:123, Sample artist - Sample title
C:\Documents and Settings\I\My Music\Sample.mp3
 
#EXTINF:321,Example Artist - Example title
C:\Documents and Settings\I\My Music\Greatest Hits\Example.ogg
```

When starting the playlist with an audio-player like *mpv* this should jump directly to your desired offset `1873` seconds:

> So, if the list is 123 minutes, it would start at 31 minutes 13 seconds

Comment: ⚠️ Warning: I did not test this. So please give me feedback if it worked for you.